# What is the best way to order an array classes?

Tags: php

I have an array where all positions are objects. Each object has an "order" property and I want to order the array by this property.

What is the best way?

I saw about `array_multisort`, but this not work I think because the positions are objects and not arrays.

Comment: can you show us your array and what O/P you need ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
<?php
class OrderedItem
{
    public $title;
    public $order;

    public function __construct($title, $order)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->order = $order;
    }
}

$items = [
    new OrderedItem('Title 1.2', 1),
    new OrderedItem('Title 3', 3),
    new OrderedItem('Title 4', 4),
    new OrderedItem('Title 1.1', 1),
    new OrderedItem('Title 2', 2),
];

usort($items, function (OrderedItem $i1, OrderedItem $i2) {
    return ($i1->order < $i2->order) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

As a result, `$items` array will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => OrderedItem Object
        (
            [title] => Title 1.1
            [order] => 1
        )

    [1] => OrderedItem Object
        (
            [title] => Title 1.2
            [order] => 1
        )

    [2] => OrderedItem Object
        (
            [title] => Title 2
            [order] => 2
        )

    [3] => OrderedItem Object
        (
            [title] => Title 3
            [order] => 3
        )

    [4] => OrderedItem Object
        (
            [title] => Title 4
            [order] => 4
        )

)
```

If in your case 'order' property is `private` you can create a static method inside your object class to compare 'order' properties. You can find an example how to do it in official doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#example-5639